# Why doesn't Android use shared libraries?

Tags: android, linux, libraries

In Android if you use a library in your app (such as the [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)) the code for the library is duplicated on the device for each app that uses it.

Why can't android use the linux ["shared library"](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) concept, so each app wouldn't have to duplicate the library's code?

Comment: Because someone at Google remembers Dll Hell?

Answer (score 4):

This is largely due to the security model. On Android, each application runs in its own silo. This is completely different to a desktop OS, where all applications have full access to all the user's data.

If we have two applications, A and B, that both use a shared library. If they used the same copy, then potentially application A could break into application B's silo - which is not desired.

As paulkayuk comments, this is also to avoid [DLL Hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell) - problems caused by applications expecting different versions of a shared library. These days storage is cheap - even on mobile - so avoiding DLL Hell is more important than saving a bit of storage space.

Comment: The main advantage of centralized storage isn't disk space, it's that there is only one place where you need to apply a bug or even security fix.

Comment: @CodesInChaos or create a bug in 3rd party code due to upgrading a shared library. DLL hell was not fun.

Comment: @WyattBarnett I'm generally a fan of putting everything my application needs in the application directory, the security/bug fix issue is the only significant downside I know of.

Comment: @WyattBarnett: Well, Linux distributions seem to handle shared libraries fine. But yes, without somebody managing it it's serious trouble.

Comment: The argument about security model is totally bogus. In Linux different users also use the same shared libraries and it does not allow them to step on each others toes. Of course application A using library provided by package B would have to trust package B, but it still does it when it includes a copy.

Comment: @JanHudec -- yes nowadays with well developed package management; it will at least keep you from melting down the machine. I do remember the excitement of upgrading apache in bygone eras though . . .

Comment: @JanHudec - I respectfully disagree. The security model is completely different between Linux and Android. Further discussion is beyond the scope of comments, but feel free to ask a separate question.

Comment: @paj28: The security model has different goal, but it uses the same tools (Android _is_ Linux), just it uses them to separate applications instead of users. Users using the same shared library is exactly the same as applications on Android doing so. Not a problem (and by the way, the standard library _is_ shared on Android; it _must_ be, because it is most closely tied to the kernel version in use).

Answer (score 1):

Android does have a facility for sharing libraries, but it is a little cumbersome to use so seems to be rarely used in practice. Applications that use Google Play Services, for instance, use this model.

The support library, however, specifically does not use this facility because it is expected that applications may be closely tied to a specific version of it, and the shared library system only allows a single version to be installed at a time.